# Failing to delete node based on attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to delete a XML Node based on one of the attributes of the node.

The XML structure looks like this:

```
<root>
    <outer>
        <Series  InstanceUID="" TimeStamp="" Delete="true">
          <Image InstanceUID="" File="" TimeStamp=""/>
          <Image InstanceUID="" File="" TimeStamp=""/>
        </Series>
        <Series  InstanceUID="" TimeStamp="" Delete="true">
          <Image InstanceUID="" File="" TimeStamp=""/>
          <Image InstanceUID="" File="" TimeStamp=""/>
        </Series>
        <Series  InstanceUID="" TimeStamp="" Delete="false">
          <Image InstanceUID="" File="" TimeStamp=""/>
          <Image InstanceUID="" File="" TimeStamp=""/>
        </Series>
    </outer>
</root>
```

If the delete attribute is equal to true, the entire node should be deleted.

```
XElement _XML = XElement.Load(fileLocation);
_XML.Descendants("outer")
    .Elements("Series")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("Delete").Value == "true")
    .Remove();
```

The query seems to be picking up the correct node, since if I replace Remove() with a Select( x=>x), it picks up the delete = "true" nodes.
What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you've posted relevant xml and code? First: your xml is not well-formed (it should be `</Series>`, not `<Series/>` as closing tag). Second: `_XML.Descendants("outer").Elements("Series")` for the xml you've posted will not return anything since `<outer>` is `_XML` itself.

Comment: Woops sorry, this is a quick snippet I just made up, I'll edit that right away.

Comment: Well, now I've just picked your updated xml and code and run it. It deletes both nodes having `Delete="true"` for me. So what's wrong here? ;)

Comment: Wait... after deleting the nodes, do I have to do something else to update the actual .xml file?

Comment: Surely. Something like `_XML.Save(fileLocation);`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that was necessary, since I've never actually edited xml files before! Would you like to post an answer so I could mark it as correct, or should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have modified `XElement` you've loaded your original xml into - you need to save changes back since after loading data `XElement` is not somehow "connected" anymore with source file.

So add something like this to your code:

```
_XML.Save(fileLocation);
```